# Plugin Utils not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I installed tha cakephp Utils plugin via composer, and then I loaded all plugins in my bootstrap.php file, I added a field in my database model for the image path (cause I want to upload image profile using Uploadable), and then I add the following code I my model table:

```
$this->addBehavior('Utils.Uploadable', [
        'foto_dir',
    ]);
```

but when I access the model I get the following error:

> Utils.UploadableBehavior could not be found.
>
> Make sure your plugin Utils is in the C:\wamp\www\siec2\plugins\ directory and was loaded.

Screenshot:

[image: cakephp page error][1]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins installed with composer are stored inside the vendor folder. Please make sure, you have the Utils Plugin in the following folder `/vendor/cakemanger/cakephp-utils`

If so, check cakephp-plugins.php inside the vendor folder for this:

```
return [
  'plugins' => [
    ...
    'Utils' => $baseDir . '/vendor/cakemanager/cakephp-utils/'
  ]
];
```

Also make sure, you loaded the plugin in your bootstrap.php: `Plugin::load('Utils');`

See [Plugins Section](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#plugin-map-file) on CakeBook.